# Is there a way to define a static property or method using the OLOO pattern or factory function pattern?

Tags: javascript, object, oop, prototypal-inheritance

Below is a code example for creating bike objects using the OLOO object creation pattern.

```
let bikePrototype = {
  init(make, model, brand) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.brand = brand;
    return this;
  },

  info() {
    return `${this.brand} ::: ${this.model}`;
  }
};

let duke = Object.create(bikePrototype).init('Duke', '2020', 'KTM');
console.log(duke.info());
console.log(duke.__proto__.constructor === Object);
console.log(duke.__proto__.constructor.name === 'Object');
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(duke).constructor === Object);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(duke).constructor.name === 'Object');
```

Answer (score 0):

[As mdn says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static):

> The static keyword defines a static method or property for a class, or
> a class static initialization block (see the link for more information
> about this usage).

[The static properties and methods are assigned to the class function](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-static-property-and-method-in-javascript) instead of to the prototype of the class function. So, we cannot call the static method and properties using the instance of the class. However, we can access the property and method directly using the class name.

So let me show an example where `static` is used and basic rules of its usage.

```
class Bike{
  static color = "green"; //static property 

  constructor(make, model, brand) {
    this.name = make ;
    this.model = model;
    this.brand = brand;
  }

  static printBike(bike){ // static method 
    console.log(`Name - ${bike.name } \nModel - ${bike.model} \nBrand - ${Bike.color}`);
  }
}

let bike = new Bike('Duke', '2020', 'KTM'); 

console.log("Accessing Bike.color static property"); 
console.log(Bike.color);

console.log("Calling static method Bike.printBike"); 
Bike.printBike(bike);

console.log(bike.color); // undefined because static property not available in instance 
console.log(bike.printBike); // undefined because static method not available in instance
```